# Using Caliburn.Micro & Telerik controls - is this possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik, caliburn.micro

I created a simple WPF MVVM app based on Caliburn.Micro for a testing purpose and it works fine: binding, events, etc.
But all that stops once I add a Telerik control to my View (in my case I used RadMap), so once I do it the events stop working at all.
Is this possible to use Caliburn along with Telerik or it's impossible? And if possible, what should I change?

Comment: Are you perhaps using Caliburn Micro's conventions (setting view model's property names as x:Name of a control)? If yes, then it won't work until you've set up conventions for the Telerik controls you want to use.

Comment: No, I know there are 2 ways of binding in Caliburn, so I don't use binding convention names, I used Bind attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had a problem with telerik and Caliburn.Micro (used it in WPF and Silverlight)

Could you show your view and viewmodel, AppBootstrapper. I think something wrong with your Binding

Comment: The code is published above. The binding is correct because everything works until I add a RadMap control

Answer (score 0):

Here are more details regarding my code:

The ViewModel:

```
   public class TestViewModel: PropertyChangedBase
    {

        private string _name = "Superman1";
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Name);
            }
        }


        private string _psition;
        public string Position
        {
            get { return _psition; }
            set
            {
                _psition = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Position);
            }
        }


        public void NameChanged()
        {
            Name = "Batman";
        }


        public void MouseMoveHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point p = e.GetPosition((Grid)sender);

            Position = string.Format("X:{0}  Y:{1}", p.X, p.Y);
        }

    }
```

The Bootstrapper:

```
public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    public AppBootstrapper()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayRootViewFor<TestViewModel>();
    }
}
```

And here's the View:

```
<Grid  cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseMove] = [Action MouseMoveHandler($source, $eventArgs)]" 
        Width="500" Height="500" Background="LightBlue">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Name="TextBoxControll" 
                Text="{Binding Name}"
                FontSize="40"
                Grid.Row="0"/>

        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Text="{Binding Position}"
                FontSize="40"
                Grid.Row="1"/>


        <Button Grid.Row="2" FontSize="30" 
                cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action NameChanged]">
            Click Me</Button>


       <telerik:RadMap  Grid.Row="3"/>

    </Grid>
```

So if I want my code to work, I have to remove all the Telerik related tags and (that's even not enought!) I also have to remove the references!
The code works only after everything telerik related gets removed.

If after that I simply drag radMap to the view, without even using it, caliburn stops working: the button click event and any other event, stops working

Answer (score 0):

Did you add all references for rad map control?

> Telerik.Windows.Controls
>
> Telerik.Windows.Data
>
> Telerik.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization

I just created a project using your code and everything work fine

Comment: Try to add RadMap

Answer (score 0):

Binding in Caliburn works for the "**out of box controls**" only everything else "**REQUIRES**" conventions to be created since **Caliburn.Micro** has no clue as to the nature of those controls.

Note:  You absolutely don't need x:bind for Telerik controls they work just find with for example `ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItems}"`

But to get them working with x:Bind you will need something along these lines....

https://github.com/vcaraulean/Caliburn.Micro.Telerik/blob/master/Silverlight/Caliburn.Micro.Telerik/TelerikConventions.cs

NB: this not as exhaustive as you would hope.  RadGrid is something you will never x:Bind (pretty much a guarantee, taking this one on would be time costly, with all of the crap you would have to come up with).